# Xlrd won't print anything python 3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlrd

I'm trying to read data from an excel file with xlrd but whenever I try to print anything inside the def open_file block. I don't get any errors (I tested with the try, except but it doesn't print anything either). I tested printing a random string outside that block and it works fine.

```
import xlrd, xlwt
path = r"C:\Users\...excelworksheet.xls"
def open_file(path):
     book = xlrd.open_workbook(path)
     try: print(book.nsheets)
     except: print("error")
     print(book.sheet_names())
```

Comment: It's not a block, it's a function and you have to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

Use main and call open_file

```
if __name__=="__main__":
     open_file(path):
```